# hibernate bulkupdate: update query syntax

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

when i update a table using hibernate

```
getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate("UPDATE Channel SET number = 40 AND active = 0");
```

i get error:  `ERROR [PARSER]: unexpected token: AND`

evething run well if i remove `AND active = 0`

i dont know how to correct this query.

help me pls, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Channel SET number = 40, active = 0
```